# Having trouble iterating over a JSON response

Tags: python

Edited - The issue I was having is that I was approaching this as if the first element in the list was all of the dicts themselves, thus stating `results_dict` with `[0]`. By doing that, I was continually only referencing the first dict in the list.

Iterating over the JSON response below is creating the same duplicate results in the list I am appending to, rather than iterating over each dict and appending each unique value.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
results_dict = [{'keywordText': 'fake toddler makeup', 'matchType': 'broad'}, {'keywordText': 'kid makeup kit girl', 'matchType': 'broad'}, {'keywordText': 'toddler makeup', 'matchType': 'broad'}]
asins = ['B087CRJ6KZ', 'B08QVDGPG4']
results = {}
suggested_kws = []

for asin in asins:
    for kw in results_dict:
        kw = results_dict[0]['keywordText']
        suggested_kws.append(kw)
        
    results[asin] = suggested_kws

print(results)
```

current result:

```
{'B087CRJ6KZ': ['fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup'],
'B08QVDGPG4': ['fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup', 'fake toddler makeup']}
```

expected result:

```
{'B087CRJ6KZ': ['fake toddler makeup', 'kid makeup kit girl', 'toddler makeup'], 
'B08QVDGPG4': ['fake toddler makeup', 'kid makeup kit girl', 'toddler makeup']}
```

Comment: Can you explain why `results_dict[0]['keywordText']` would be anything but `fake toddler makeup`?

Comment: I have a list of 3 dicts. I am iterating over them. For each dict, I am trying to get the value corresponding to the key 'keywordText'. Since each value for this key, for each dict, is different, I would expect different results

Comment: Yes, I understood the question. I'm asking why you think that particular value would ever change? This is what you are doing wrong

Comment: I would expect it to change because for every loop through the For loop, I am now referencing a different dict, with a different value for that key.

Comment: You are not using the variable that you create `kw` when looping over `results_dict` .
Instead, you use the original list `results_dict[0]['keywordText']` which always grabs:
`{'keywordText': 'fake toddler makeup', 'matchType': 'broad'}`

Comment: I assume you wanted `kw['keywordText']`? Not `results_dict[0]`? That `results_dict[0]` value never changes, regardless of any loop

Comment: I see it now. Not sure what I was thinking when indexing the list that way. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict-comprehension here.

```
results_dict = [{'keywordText': 'fake toddler makeup', 'matchType': 'broad'}, {'keywordText': 'kid makeup kit girl', 'matchType': 'broad'}, {'keywordText': 'toddler makeup', 'matchType': 'broad'}]
asins = ['B087CRJ6KZ', 'B08QVDGPG4']

results = {a: [x['keywordText'] for x in results_dict] for a in asins}
```